# Trouble with getting total messages in Discord.Py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

So, I've been scratching my head for the last hour or so with getting the total messages from all the text channels into the CSV file. Everything else works great, except for the bolded part.

Edit: well, if you put inside the code sample, it doesn't show the bolded part. So I'll remove it.

I know that API documentation mentions the method:

```
counter = 0
async for message in channel.history(limit=200):
    if message.author == client.user:
        counter += 1
```

Also, failed to mention it, but if I do it separately, it does work, the code I got it from another post, a bit finicky, since I have only done it with one user.

This is the command that I had it to work:

```
@bot.command(name="message")
async def get_messages(ctx):
    userMessages = []
    userID = 123456# Change this to the ID of the user you are looking messages for
    channelID = 7890123# Change this to the channel ID of the messages you want to check for

    channel = bot.get_channel(channelID)
    user = discord.utils.find(lambda m: m.id== userID, channel.guild.members)
    
    counter = 0
    async for message in channel.history(limit=):
        print(channel.name)
        if message.author == user:
            counter += 1

    print(counter)
```

But I just can't seem to be able to implement it into my script.

This is my command:

```
# bot.py
import os
import random
import discord
import csv
import io
import datetime


from discord.ext import commands
from dotenv import load_dotenv

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True  # Subscribe to the privileged members intent.
intents.messages = True  # Subscribe to the privileged members intent.

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')

month = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='&', intents=intents)
@bot.command(name="lista",help="Creates member list")
async def get_members(ctx):
    file = 'log.csv'     
    await ctx.message.delete()
    with io.open(file, "w", encoding="utf-8",newline='') as output:
        writer = csv.writer(output)
        writer.writerow(['list of roles']
        includeChannels = ['list of channels']
        for guild in bot.guilds:            
            for member in ctx.guild.members:
                roles = []
                for role in member.roles:
                    exists = role.name in excludeRoles
                    if exists == False:
                        roles.append(role.name)
                    f = ' '.join(roles)                
                for channel in ctx.guild.text_channels:
                    async for message in channel.history():
                        if message.author == str(member):
                            a = "okay"
                writer.writerow([str(member),member.display_name,member.joined_at.strftime("%d-%m-%Y"),f,a])

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

The error I get is the 403 forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing permission.

Edit 2:
Alright, thanks to @makonede, I was able to be able to not display an error, but, I can't seem to be able to get the counter, even though I has actually tested that both message.author and user appear as the same, with the name#id, I separated the counter command into a new one, just to get more attention in the problem, it goes up to the last if, but never goes inside of it to counter. Maybe there's something I'm missing, but, I'm stumped:

```
@bot.command(name="message",help="Creates member list")
async def history(ctx):
  includeChannels = ['family-chat', 'children-only-chat', 'pictures', 'food', 'support-hype','babies-and-toddlers-chat']
  await ctx.message.delete()    
  for guild in bot.guilds:
    for member in ctx.guild.members:
      counter = 0
      for channel in guild.text_channels:
        exists = channel.name in includeChannels
        if exists == True:
          try:
            async for message in channel.history(limit=100,after=month):
              if str(bot.user) == str(message.author):
                counter+=1
          except discord.Forbidden:
            pass
          print(counter)
```

Comment: Please post the **full** traceback, not just a part of it.

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński done

Comment: @RafaelHernandez I still do not see the full traceback... "*The error I get is the 403 forbidden 50001.*" is not the full traceback.

Comment: Sorry >_< new to Python, I hope I get it right now, I uploaded the cmd image, and also the full error code.

Comment: This error is actually self-explanatory. Your bot does not seem to have the necessary access permissions to the channel.

Answer (score 1):

One of the text channels in one of the servers your bot has access to has Read Message History disabled for the bot. Simple error handling does the trick:

```py
try:
    async for message in channel.history():
        if message.author == str(member):
            a = "okay"
except discord.Forbidden:
    pass
```

Comment: this worked, thanks! , I did the change, and it does seem to have worked, but, now it doesn't seem to add up the counter, I have already edited my original post, and separated at the last part.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, after a week of trying, I have resolved the problem. I changed a bit of my initial code, because if I had the bot in another server it would double the users, so that's something I want. So, here it's the code:

```
@bot.command(name="log",help="Sends a list of members, with roles, and join date")
async def get_members(ctx):
    file = 'log.csv'
    await ctx.message.delete()    
    with io.open(file, "w", encoding="utf-8",newline='') as output:
        writer = csv.writer(output)
        writer.writerow(['Name','Server Name','Joined At','Roles','ID','Messages'])
        excludeRoles = ['roles']        
        channel = bot.get_channel(788762422050553867)
        messages = await channel.history(limit=None,after=sunday).flatten()
        for member in ctx.guild.members:
            roles = []
            counter = 0
            for role in member.roles:
                exists = role.name in excludeRoles
                if exists == False:
                    roles.append(role.name)
                f = ' '.join(roles)
            for message in messages:
                if message.author == member:
                    counter+=1
            writer.writerow([str(member),member.display_name,member.joined_at.strftime("%d-%m-%Y"),f,'id: '+str(member.id),counter])
                
        await ctx.send(file=discord.File(fp='log.csv'), content="Here is the list of members that are on the discord, with their joined dates and roles, and how many messages have they sent in #support-hype")
```

So what it does, it extracts the name, server's name, when did they joined, their roles and finally how many messages have they sent in a particular channel.